# javascript: перевести дату в строку в произвольном формате

Tags: javascript, datetime, format

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно перевести дату

```
const today = new Date();
```

в строку в формате `YYYY-MM-DD` средствами javascript (без использования сторонних библиотек, типа moment.js)

конечно можно собрать строку из чисел "в лоб", но есть ли нормальное решение?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62394749/6104996  - оно?

Comment: `new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]` подходит? (Но пояса не учитываются)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, ну в принципе это решение в лоб с перебором одной даты в другую через раскладывания ее на части, хотя наверное такой вариант тоже подойдет, но думал, что можно обойтись каким-то встроенным простым решением

Answer (score 1):

решил в лоб, учитывая, что для вывода на экран использовалась уже дата в обычном формате DD.MM.YYYY:

```
const today = new Date();
const dateSrc = today.toLocaleString('ru-RU', { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' });
    
dateDst = dateSrc.split(".").reverse().join("-");
```